# How to create comment block in visual studio fast?

Tags: visual-studio

In Eclipse I can just type /* and enter, and it would form a perfect comment block for complex comments above the code:

```
/*
 *
 */
```

How to do the same or similar in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language? I'm going to assume C++.

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Brace Completion > Complete Multiline Comments > True`

This setting will do exactly what you describe. Typing `/*` will auto-complete the `*/` and any new line entered after `/*` will auto-insert a new `*` at the beginning of the line.

Alternatively:

1. Download and install Visual Assist: https://www.wholetomato.com/
2. Highlight code to be commented.
3. `Shift + 8` or `*` on the keypad.
4. Profit.

Comment: I'm using vscode. I can't find `Tools` in Visual Studio Code? Only `File > Preferences > Settings`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the code you want to comment and press ctrl + /